# Titanium How to load XML in a webview?

Tags: xml, webview, titanium

Im programming in Titanium for iOS/Android, and i need to load an XML in a webview.
I need to load XML directly in the webview, not from a XML file.

So, i need to use webview.setHtml(...) instead of webview.url(...). It works, the webview shows the content, but setHtml() method doesn't load correctly the XSL style file.

I try using url() method, it works and the XSL style file loads correctly. But is not good solution for me, because i need to do directly, without a XML file.

Example, if i do like this, it works with the XSL:

```
webview.url='test.xml';
```

But this one, shows the content of the XML without the XSL style:

```
webview.setHtml('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><?xml-stylesheethref
="test.xsl" type="text/xsl"?><result><entry><form><orth>ahardi</orth><sf
_set><sf sort="ahardi">.........');
```

Why is this happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post some code showing what you are trying to do.

Comment: OK, i add an example of what im trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first example works:

```
webview.url='test.xml';
```

You can write the XML information you are generating out to a file and just use the webview.url again.